# Session cookie expires on the next page after it is set?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have two pages in PHP where the first one creates a cookie using `session_set_cookie_params(30 * 60,"/","/",false);` and the next page tries to retrieve the cookie (using `session_get_cookie_params()`) to display the time left on the cookie but for some reason I only get zero time left.

This is the cookie set page

```
<?php
 session_set_cookie_params(30 * 60,"/","/",false); 
 session_start();   
 $array = session_get_cookie_params();
 echo $array['lifetime'];    
 ?>
```

and this is the page that starts the session and retrieves the cookie

```
<?php
 session_start();   
 $array = session_get_cookie_params();
 echo $array['lifetime']; 
 ?>
```

Comment: So what actual expiration time is set?

Comment: I thought it was 1800 seconds no? It's the first parameter in the set cookie function right?

Comment: I asked about the **ACTUAL** value (not about the expectation, which I obviously can calculate by myself as well). Check what value was set in the browser (or using fiddler)

Comment: When I look at the cookie in firefox it expires at the end of the session.

Comment: so use network tab in firebug or use fiddler

Comment: Yeah but what do I look for?

Comment: you're looking for the actual expiration time. It expires for the reason. And I thought that's what your question is about.

Comment: Well sort of, the question is more about the source code I posted. It should run the same everywhere no, are you running php yourself? Can you test it?

Comment: I'm not going to. If you aren't interested in solving your issue using my advices - then good luck with continuing guessing.

Comment: No problem, I think the server I'm on isn't working properly but the answer has been posted below thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter you used "/" is not a valid domain name. 
Using session_set_cookie_params(30 * 60,"/") will work. Default for 4th parameter - secure is false, no need to sepcify.

Comment: Did you test it because I still get 0.

Comment: It depends on the configuration of php.ini so it is irrelevant on my system. This function updates the runtime ini values of the corresponding PHP ini configuration keys which can be retrieved with the ini_get().

Comment: What parameter do I use for the `ini_get()` by the way? It's asking for one.

Comment: ini_get("session.cookie_lifetime"), but please keep in mind that The effect of session_set_cookie_params() only lasts for the duration of the script. Thus, you need to call session_set_cookie_params() for every request and before session_start() is called.

Comment: You mean I need to call `session_set_cookie_params()` on each and every single page?

Comment: Yes, the configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending. Add it also on the second script and test.